# How to do XML manipulation with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml

In a SQL Server I have to deal with. I have data in a column that is in this format:

```
<div firstname="Tom" lastname="Hanks" initials="TH" />
<div firstname="Tom" lastname="Hiddleston" initials="TH" />
```

This is 2 records for a column.

How can I select from this from it, and return the data in 2 columns? Like this

```
<firstname + ' ' + lastname, initials>
```

Is there a way to parse XML and extract data from it?

Answer (score 3):

You have enough reputation by now to know you *really* should be posting what you've tried...

This should help you anyway.

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE #Sample (xmldata xml);
INSERT INTO #Sample
VALUES (
'<div firstname="Tom" lastname="Hanks" initials="TH" />
<div firstname="Tom" lastname="Hiddleston" initials="TH" />');

GO
SELECT *
FROM #Sample;
GO

SELECT n.d.value('@firstname','varchar(50)') + ' ' + n.d.value('@lastname','varchar(50)') + ', ' + n.d.value('@initials','varchar(5)')
FROM #Sample S
     CROSS APPLY S.xmldata.nodes('/div') n(d);

GO

DROP TABLE #Sample;
```

Comment: that begs the question as to why new users are held to a higher standard than ones with high rep... ;)